# How to move the search icon, in the search box of jquery mobile?

Tags: search, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile's search input comes with a search box, with a search glass icon that is to the left of the box.  I want the search icon to the right side of the box.  I'm looking at the css, but the only thing I see that controls it is...

.ui-icon-searchfield::after

but just not sure if that is the right css to use to move the icon around...or is there a class or data attribute I can use on the search element itself, to move the icon?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified the class correctly. All you need to do is override the background's position to be roughly textbox's width + 73px, e.g.:

```
.ui-icon-searchfield::after {
    left: 173px !important;
}
```

​Check my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/wyeUu/

not sure what you want to do about the "clear" icon, which appears on the right when you type.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the clear icon after some testing!  And thank you for the example as well!